# How to disable the message "could not access file" in PHP mailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I am using PHPMailer for sending mail from form with multiple attachments.
This is a part of the form:

```
 Attachment:<br />
<input type="file" name="attach1" id="attach1" />
<input type="file" name="attach2" id="attach2" />
<input type="file" name="attach3" id="attach3" />
```

When a user attaches only 1 or 2 files, I added some condition in my email.php:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['attach1'] ))
{
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attach1']['tmp_name']); // bijlage 1
}
if(!empty($_FILES['attach2']))
{
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attach2']['tmp_name']); // bijlage 2
}
if(!empty($_FILES['attach3']))
{
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attach3']['tmp_name']); // bijlage 3
}
```

But I still got the message "could not access file" on the empty input fields.
The attachments are being sent correctly to the email address even with this message. But I want to get rid of it when I use only 1 or 2 attachments.

Comment: dont disable the message, work out why you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right. This line :

```
if(!empty($_FILES['attach3']))..
```

isn't equal `false` ( array in `$_FILES['attach3']` isn't empty: it has ,e.g, error code eq 4 (`UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`) in `$_FILES['attach3']['error']` and some another fields) when you send only 1 and 2 attachements => you see message with `"could not access file"` in third case. You need to change checks to:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['attach1']['name'] ))....

if(!empty($_FILES['attach2']['name'] ))....

if(!empty($_FILES['attach3']['name'] ))....
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this wrong - you should use `move_uploaded_file` before accessing the files in $_FILES, as per [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) and [the example code provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).